# Serialize only the collection of the class

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

I have a following class.

```
class Timesheet
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public List<Employee> Approvers { get; set; }
        public Employee Resource { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
```

And I need to serialize only the List Approvers and not the other properties.
Currently I'm using the following code

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var json = serializer.Serialize(tsheet);
```

Which returns all the properties but I need only the list items. Can anyone please tell me how can I do this?

Really appreciate the help :)

Comment: Please, do not spam with tags. Also, usage of `JavaScriptSerializer` isn't recommended

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices:

Using the [ScriptIgnoreAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute?view=netframework-4.8):

```
public class Timesheet
{
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public List<Employee> Approvers { get; set; }

    [ScriptIgnore]        
    public Employee Resource { get; set; }

    [ScriptIgnore]        
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

or I think the following should also work:

```
var json = serializer.Serialize(new { Approvers = tsheet.Approvers });
```